# Função para gerar INI a partir do Array

Tags: php, configuração

Existe uma função que faça o inverso da `parse_ini_file` para poder gerar um arquivo de configuração a partir de uma array?

Answer (score 2):

Ao que parece o PHP não possui uma função nativa para isso, você tem que criar sua própria função.

Dê uma olhada na primeira resposta dessa pergunta do SO internacional: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316873/php-array-to-a-ini-file

**#edit**

Postado originalmente por: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016221/rr no link citado acima.

```
function arr2ini(array $a, array $parent = array())
{
    $out = '';
    foreach ($a as $k => $v)
    {
        if (is_array($v))
        {
            //subsection case
            //merge all the sections into one array...
            $sec = array_merge((array) $parent, (array) $k);
            //add section information to the output
            $out .= '[' . join('.', $sec) . ']' . PHP_EOL;
            //recursively traverse deeper
            $out .= arr2ini($v, $sec);
        }
        else
        {
            //plain key->value case
            $out .= "$k=$v" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Exemplo de uso da função abaixo com uma array multi-dimensional:

```
$x = array(
  'section1' => array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'subsection' => array(
      'subkey' => 'subvalue',
      'further' => array('a' => 5),
      'further2' => array('b' => -5))));
echo arr2ini($x);
```

Também vale lembrar que não há como preservar os comentários que haviam no arquivo **INI**, seria necessário criar uma função de parse mais complexa para isso.

Comment: poderia transcrever o conteúdo do link aqui?

Comment: Fora o código a única citação útil era sobre os comentários.

Answer (score 2):

Não existe uma função nativa e estável (pelo menos até onde eu sei). Quando eu precisei fazer isso, fiz manualmente.

Existe uma extensão do PEAR chamada [Config_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Config_Lite), mas ainda é beta.

No entanto, pode-se facilmente encontrar um código, como [desta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268642/1683070):

```php
function write_ini_file($assoc_arr, $path, $has_sections=FALSE) { 
    $content = ""; 
    if ($has_sections) { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            $content .= "[".$key."]\n"; 
            foreach ($elem as $key2=>$elem2) { 
                if(is_array($elem2)) 
                { 
                    for($i=0;$i<count($elem2);$i++) 
                    { 
                        $content .= $key2."[] = \"".$elem2[$i]."\"\n"; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if($elem2=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
                else $content .= $key2." = \"".$elem2."\"\n"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    else { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            if(is_array($elem)) 
            { 
                for($i=0;$i<count($elem);$i++) 
                { 
                    $content .= $key2."[] = \"".$elem[$i]."\"\n"; 
                } 
            } 
            else if($elem=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
            else $content .= $key2." = \"".$elem."\"\n"; 
        } 
    } 

    if (!$handle = fopen($path, 'w')) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    if (!fwrite($handle, $content)) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    fclose($handle); 
    return true; 
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```php
$sampleData = array(
                'first' => array(
                    'first-1' => 1,
                    'first-2' => 2,
                    'first-3' => 3,
                    'first-4' => 4,
                    'first-5' => 5,
                ),
                'second' => array(
                    'second-1' => 1,
                    'second-2' => 2,
                    'second-3' => 3,
                    'second-4' => 4,
                    'second-5' => 5,
                ));
write_ini_file($sampleData, './data.ini', true);
```

Por outro lado, minha sugestão pessoal é usar Json para armazenar dados. Além de ser mais flexível (hierarquia, tipos de dados), já existem funções nativas para [ler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) e [criar](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) a partir de uma String qualquer.