# Qual a diferença de função e diretiva?

Tags: php, ini

Como sei o que é uma função do PHP, o que é uma diretiva, o que é um módulo e o que é uma biblioteca?

Estou iniciando no PHP, possuo algumas perguntas que talvez para muitos sejam básicas, mas para muitos outros é o inicio.

Comment: Qual o contexto da diretiva? Dê uma exemplo de diretiva que você viu.

Comment: Da um exemplo de uma diretiva? Relacionadas: [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/91) e [O que são módulos na programação?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129254/91)

Comment: Por exemplo oque eu vejo no info php, aquelas informações como são chamadas ?

Comment: No php.ini oque são aquelas informações?

Comment: @Welliton.O A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo ler a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php). Sim, toda ela. Eu sei que quase ninguém fará, mas não deixa de ser o ideal.

O que tem no `php.ini` nada tem a ver com a linguagem. Aquilo é configuração do ambiente do PHP. Ali tem parâmetros de como o PHP deve funcionar. O que deve ser carregado, se deve ou não fazer alguma coisa, os limites de alguns recursos, onde encontrar certas coisas que o PHP precisa, coisas deste tipo. Aí teria que ver dúvidas específicas ou [estudar a documentação do `php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php).

É possível [alterar as configurações durante a execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11127/101).

Funções são trechos de código que executam um algoritmo e geralmente produzem um resultado. [Já foi respondido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101).

[Biblioteca já foi respondida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101).

[Módulo também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129254/101). E [especificamente para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187039/101).